# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.(Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

First I have created an environment in anaconda navigator in which i have installed packages like Keras,Tensorflow and Theano.

Now I have activated my environment through anaconda navigator and have launched the Spyder Application.
Now When i try to import keras it is showing error stating that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Quickhotshot612\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Quickhotshot612\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Quickhotshot612\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Quickhotshot612\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Quickhotshot612\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

And is continuously the showing the error like an infinite.
Where did i  go wrong? Anyone help me with this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCybv.png)

But when i give (import theano),it is working,but does'nt in the case of tensorflow and keras.

Comment: Can u writedown how did you tried to import `keras`. And you really shouldn't install keras anymore since its included in tf natively. Just install tensorflow and then import `keras` functions as `tensorflow.keras`.

Comment: i gave "import keras" and tried to execute this line of code.

Comment: Also i installed tensorflow by first activating the environment,then i gave "conda install tensorflow==1.15" then when i try to import it is not coming.

Comment: I see you are using conda. As tf 2.0 is not currently supported in conda your best bet it to install it via pip. I suggest you to create a new clean environment, activate it then install with `pip install tensorflow`. This will install latest `tf` with builtin `keras`. After the installation import `keras` with the statement `import tensorflow.keras`. AFAIK in tensorflow 1.15, keras is a standalone package and therefore you should install it seperately.

Comment: now i've installed tensorflow 1.15 in my environment and yeah created a new one.Now if i give "import tensorflow" it is importing the lib without any error but if i give "import tensorflow.keras" it is showing some import error saying that it detected an older version of numpy.What do i do now?

Comment: As I told earlier, you better not use tensorflow 1.15 version. You need to install keras seperately if you do so. Just install latest tensorflow (version 2) which has integrated keras and bleeding edge. Then you can `import tensorflow.keras`

Comment: now i fully uninstalled tensorflow library fully from my env and first i upgraded my pip to 20.0.2. Then now i am installing tensorflow 2

Comment: And i installed it with no errors.Now if i give "import tensorflow", the same first import error is coming.I've been caught up in a loop man! It is stating that ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Should i run tensorflow on gpu?Will this fix my prob?

Comment: Have you installed `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Stuido 2015`. It should be installed on your system.

Comment: hey i got it working.I directly installed the library through navigator without using cmd.Can i use all keras functions using tensorflow.keras

Comment: Ya i have the latest Microsoft visual c++ Redistributable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,I kinda figured out and it works for me!

1)Check pip,setuptools and wheel are up to date.
2)If u get an error during installation with the wrapt library."conda remove wrapt" and then "pip install tensorflow"
3)Also u should have the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Stuido 2015 installed in your computer or a higher version.
4)Then try to import tensorflow or tensorflow.keras

If this still shows ImportError. Open the navigator and and install tensorflow from there directly  by selecting that environment and going to Not installed and then search for tensorflow and download the package.It will automatically add the package to your environment and open say spyder and try to import tensorflow in kernal.

This works fine.

Even if u have a pip error i.e cannot import name 'Flowcontrol', U can try this method.

Peace!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by downgrade tensorflow to version 2.0

```
pip install --user tensorflow==2.0
```

per Github [enter link description here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749)

My platform:
win10
python 3.7
tensorflow 2.1